# The expression contains invalid date constant

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I tried this code first before copying it to my main project (I created new project to test the codes first):

```
Private Sub posBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles posBtn.Click
    On Error GoTo wewe

    If posText.Text = "" Then
        Call notFound()
        Exit Sub

    Else

        Dim cantFind As String = posText.Text

        EmployeesRecordBindingSource.Filter = "(Convert(#_of_Employees, 'System.String') LIKE '" & posText.Text & "')" & "OR (last_name LIKE '" & posText.Text & "') OR (first_name LIKE '" & posText.Text & "')" & "OR (mi LIKE '" & posText.Text & "') OR (position LIKE '" & posText.Text & "')"

        If EmployeesRecordBindingSource.Count <> 0 Then
            With DataGridView2
                .DataSource = EmployeesRecordBindingSource
            End With
        Else

            MsgBox(cantFind & vbNewLine & "The search item was not found!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Hey boss")

            EmployeesRecordBindingSource.Filter = Nothing

            With DataGridView2
                .ClearSelection()
                .DataSource = EmployeesRecordBindingSource
            End With


        End If
    End If


lul:
    Exit Sub

wewe:

    MsgBox("Error Number " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & "Error Description " & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Reset Error!")
    Resume lul

End Sub
```

In my sample project, this is working. But when I copied it to my main project and run, I got this error: `The expression contains invalid date constant '#_ofE_Employees, 'Sytem.String') LIKE '1')OR` and so on... Did I missed something? Btw, it is for searching in datagridview. I have also private sub for reset, notfound.

Comment: Try `& " OR` instead of `& "OR`.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it :)

Comment: I got the same error :(

Comment: I remove the `" & "` before the `OR`. In my sample project, it works, but in my main, got the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields cannot start with the `#` as it is used for dates.

You might reconsider using `signs` and `numbers` when creating `fields` and `variables` in both your platform and database because there are chances those are reserved.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works fine now :) I didn't know that I can't use signs or numbers in database. I'll be careful now, thanks again :)

Comment: _...there are chances those are reserved._ I think it's not a good exercise (just an opinion).

Comment: I think now too. I keep searching the net for the solution and can't find one. So I decided to ask it here. I'll take note about that, sir :)